# Javascript/Node.js - How to assign the output from a node-fetch to a var (Node-Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am writing some code for a program, but I'm not able to figure out how to assign the output of a fetch to a variable. Here's my code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var totalNumOfPages;

fetch('https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auctions')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(totalPages => totalNumOfPages = totalPages)

console.log(totalNumOfPages)
```

The output is undefined, rather than the value of "totalPages" taken from the api. How can I assign the value of totalPages to the var totalNumOfPages.

Comment: This seems like you're doing the correct thing. What happens if you log the `totalPages` directly inside the last `.then()`? Does it still log undefined?

Comment: Nope, it logs the correct value if I do console.log.

Comment: Ahh, I was noticing that something similar was happening when I logged totalNumOfPages inside a .then() as well as logging it outside, It would print undefined, then the desired value, which I thought was odd. How do I fix the problem then?

Comment: My previous comment disappeared for some reason. Look at the linked questions at the top of your own. Your question has been marked as a duplicate since someone else already asked the same question. The answers to the other questions should help you.

Comment: See the duplicate answers, but basically fetch is asynchronous, this console.log gets run before fetch completes. If you put the call in a async function and put await in front of fetch it will print. Side note, I would return the value instead. `const totalNumOfPages = await fetch(...)`